# Is there any way test Android Pay integration without having valid credit card?

Tags: integration, android-pay

I am trying to test android pay integration.but for that it seems we need to have a valid Credit Card.Are there any test cards that android pay accepts.

Answer (score 0):

There're no test cards for android pay.
Android Pay allows to add only valid cards.  However in Environment test mode the card will not be charged.